# squidGuard hangs during setup

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

I am trying to set up squidGuard, but when I run the following nothing happens. No cpu/disk/network activity it just hangs. What may be wrong?

```
sudo -u proxy squidGuard -C all
```

Comment: Add a `-d`.  What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Black lists must be in correct place.

if config cantains

```
dbhome /var/lib/squidguard/db

dest xxxx {
        domainlist xxxx/domains
        urllist xxxx/urls
}
```

then files `/var/lib/squidguard/db/xxxx/domains` and `/var/lib/squidguard/db/xxxx/urls` must exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
squidGuard -d -b -P -C all
```

It will show you more infos on what's happening

Logs directories:
/usr/local/squidGuard/log
/var/log/squid